# Function to name column with different recurring numbers in R

Tags: r, date, rename

So I converted annual homeless figures into a time series and aggregated them, so I'm left with the average figure for the quarter. The first entry is Q4 2014, and the last entry is Q4 2020. I want to write a function that converts the name of the 'Date' column (which doesn't convert when I change the dataframe to a timeseries so this column is otherwise useless once I have aggregated my data) to say what year and quarter the entry is from e.g. Q3 2017, Q4 2017, Q1 2018, etc.

It can't use the date of the entry to create the names, and it must make the first entry Q4 2014.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_string <- "Q1 2018"
quarter <- substr(date_string, start=1, stop=2)
year <- substr(date_string, start=6, stop=8)

time_period <- paste(quarter, year, sep="-")
time_period
```

There may be more elegant ways but this is dead simple & illustrative.

Answer (score 0):

Hi my answer using lubridate::

```
library(lubridate)

today<-Sys.Date()


> today
[1] "2021-03-28"

paste0("Q",quarter(today)," ",year(today))

[1] "Q1 2021"
```